# VB.NET GET request to Web API with Bearer Token and Body Text - Errors

Tags: vb.net, request

I need your advice please.

I am making WebRequest to download data using API. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.
API is working as expected and was tested in Postman . co site. Below are image request parameters.
GET, Authorization, Bearer Token.
Body, Raw, Text, Text String input para.json below

[postman 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XNktTt6Db7doAAKxx0MZJ40Y5FGlmvLo/view?usp=sharing)

[postman 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yk0P6f3gPb4x3sWcWyPWrfEfkJbukaQh/view?usp=sharing)

```
enter Sub Test()

Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\para.json")
Dim Tokenx as string = "549539487523948576293485629384756293847"
Dim result As String
Dim request = CType(url, HttpWebRequest)

request.ContentType = "text"
request.Headers.Add(AuthorizationX)
request.Method = "POST"

    Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
        streamWriter.Write(json)
    End Using

    Dim response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Using streamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Below are images of errors

When method is POST,

> Error 405: Method not allowed

When method is GET,

> Error: Cannot send the content body with this verb-type

para.json

```json
[
    {
        "site": "1339",
        "po": "55090925",
        "line": 6
    },
    {
        "site": "1339",
        "po": "55090925",
        "line": 10
    },
    {
        "site": "1339",
        "po": "55090926",
        "line": 34
    }
]
```

[error-1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TlK74R4Z6EzXQDC925wRf1Yyb8BXmS63/view?usp=sharing)

[error-2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-HfirZfTtxAFk-tdEiJAM5uXsf0bnys/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: any help will be much appreciated. been days looking for answer now

Comment: Well, I know not much help with the actual question, but you did ask what you're doing wrong :) Perhaps a read over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-6.0 first. Particularly the section _We don't recommend that you use HttpWebRequest for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class._